# Is there a stronger version of "even"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Oxford Dictionary defines the adverb *even* as:

> used to emphasize something surprising or extreme.
>   "they have never even heard of the US"
>   *synonyms:* surprisingly, unexpectedly, paradoxically
>   "even the best hitters missed the ball"
>
> - used in comparisons for emphasis.
>     "he knows even less about it than I do"
>     *synonyms:* still, yet, more, all the more
>     "it got even colder"

Is there a stronger version of this? My example is:

> The LHC machine, even when it found the Higgs boson, _______ when it find the tachyon, is still only a combination of atoms.

Finding out the Higgs boson is already extraodinary, but being able find out the tachyon is unimaginable.

Comment: I think the standard progression is *even, ... still even* .

Comment: The LHC machine, even when it found the Higgs boson – yes, even when it finds the tachyon – is still only a combination of atoms.

Comment: The repetition of _even_ itself is what makes the construction work; why bother inflecting it?

Comment: In speech, even stronger than even is EEEven. In novels, that's typically indicated with italics, sometimes on the thing being emphasized ("The dog, even when it found a bone, even when it found a *squirrel*, would always return when I whistled"). In more formal writing, just repeat it, perhaps with some fillip like the suggestions above or "and even".

Comment: @1 I thought that it's the second "even" to be italicized?

Comment: @Ooker Yes, sometimes; my example was just to illustrate that sometimes the italics go on the thing being emphasized, *even though* we would (also) pronounce the emphasis on the EEven in speech. If that makes sense.

Comment: @JohnLawler I think it can be interpreted as "even X happens, or even Y happens"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Let alone**, [according to Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/let_alone):

> "Used to indicate that something is far less likely or suitable than something else already mentioned." [1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/let_alone)

In your sentence (also added a *will* to it grammatical):

> The LHC machine, even when it found the Higgs boson, **let alone** when it *will* find the tachyon, is still only a combination of atoms.

Other sentence from you example, my addition is in bold:

> They have never even heard of the US, **let alone Texas**.

Other example sentences [from ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/let_alone):

> "‘At the time he had no idea how to start a business, **let alone** find the financial backing to realise his dream.’"
>
> "‘There was a chance that he might not be able to breathe for himself or swallow, **let alone** walk or talk again.’"

**Attribution**

[1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/let_alone) "Let Alone | Definition of Let Alone in English by Oxford Dictionaries." Oxford Dictionaries | English. Accessed March 23, 2018. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/let_alone.

Answer (score 1):

My current choice:

> Even when the Higgs boson is found, or **even** the tachyon **will ever** be found, the LHC is only more advanced than a hoe by the number of oscillators.

*Will ever* highlights the miraculousness of finding out the tachyon, hence it makes a stronger version of even.