# Sentence connector after hardly/barely emphasizing the lack of ability/resource

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, slang, idiom-requests

What is the sentence connector that fits best in the following examples?

> He could hardly even make a profit with two employees, ..... three.
>
> She could barely even eat one pizza slice, ..... two.
>
> They hardly had enough brains to write the script for the school play, ..... the script for a Broadway play.
>
> The bear had hardly enough food for two days, ...... two weeks.

Comment: Closely related question: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/439785/71848

Comment: These meet the rules for (and are therefore all grammatical with) _let alone_, as [this answer points out](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/319151/15299).

Comment: @JJJ nice find! I did a search but obviously not as diligently ;-)  And I might add your own answer to a somewhat related question: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/438024

Answer (score 2):

### [let alone](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/let_alone)

> PHRASE
>
> Used to indicate that something is far less likely or suitable than
>   something else already mentioned.
>
> *‘he was incapable of leading a bowling team, let alone a country’*